# Using induvidual NSFetchedResultsController for each type of fetch

Tags: ios, database, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a database with many different objects that I need to retrieve. I have settled to use `NSFetchedResultsController`s to retrieve and store data. Is it the correct protocol for developers to use multiple NSFetchedResultsControllers? 
For example:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *loadDates = ...;
NSFetchedResultsController *loadMoreData = ...;
NSFetchedResultsController *loadMuchMoreData = ...;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have three tables? Generally NSFetchedResultesControllers are used in conjunction to a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should use `NSFetchRequest` to retrieve data for one-time purposes.

What `NSFetchedResultsController` is really useful for however is creating a bridge between your data and your `UITableViewController` subclass. `NSFetchedResultsController` will monitor all changes to the *managed object context* that are in the bounds of its predicate and send delegate methods to your `UITableViewController` subclass so you can update your UI.